# BSD - use any port available?

Tags: c, sockets, port, bind, bsd

All of the tutorials and examples I find online always specify a port number like 7000 or 4950 etc. What if those ports are open on one computer, but another? Seems like that case makes doing that a bad idea. Is there a way to say "find and use any open port"? My code now is like this -

```
//get server info, put into servinfo
if ((status = getaddrinfo("192.168.2.2", port, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo error: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
    return false;
}
```

with port being 4950. This is for a tcp socket, but I'm assuming it will be the same general strategy for udp?

Also quick question - if I am using both tcp and udp connections in an application, should they use different ports? (didn't feel like this deserved another question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Seems like that case makes doing that a bad idea

Not so, see below.

> Is there a way to say "find and use any open port"?

Sure, you could just not `bind` or pass `NULL` as `port`. But then, **how would the clients know where to connect to** ? You would have to publish this information somewhere.

Back to `bind(2)`. If you specify a port of `0` the kernel chooses an ephemeral port when bind is called.

Here's a quote from TLPI:

> There are other possibilities than binding a server’s socket to a
>   well-known address. For example, for an Internet domain socket, **the
>   server could omit the call to bind()** and simply call listen(), which
>   causes the kernel to choose an ephem- eral port for that socket.
>
> Afterward, the server can use  `getsockname()` to retrieve the address
>   of its socket. In this scenario, **the server must then publish that
>   address** so that clients know how to locate the server’s socket. Such
>   publication could be done by registering the server’s address with a
>   centralized directory service application that clients then contact in
>   order to obtain the address.

Back to your questions:

> Also quick question - if I am using both tcp and udp connections in an
>   application, should they use different ports

Not necessarily. They don't "get mixed up".

Comment: "how would the clients know where to connect to ?"  Oh okay, I didn't think about that. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Services like `avahi` (bonjour, mdns) were invented to resolve that issue, but it doesn't scale well beyond the local network segment.